# Dell monitors are changing some of their device naming standards

Tags: standards, naming

Dell monitors are changing some of their device naming standards eg. `C2423H` will be replaced by `P2424HEB`. Both are wide-screen 24" monitors with inbuilt cameras.

Can someone please advise however what the `HEB` stands for please?

Comment: You would have to contact Dell.  HEB could literally stand for anything.

Comment: You will need to ask Dell for that information.

Comment: perhaps the H stands for the same thing it did before, and it's only EB you need to figure out! I just lowered your work load by 33%

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a name change but a feature change, the naming convention is [Series][Diagonal][Year][Ratio or Resolution][Features] ([source](https://www.urtech.ca/2022/10/solved-video-what-dell-monitor-names-decoded/)):

The `H` stands for the resolution "HD widescreen (16:9)", and the `E` for "Ethernet connection via the RJ45 port".

Not sure about the `B` I think it's for "Video Conferencing: Webcam, Speakers & Microphone". Compare P3424WEB to P3424WE, that is the only difference.

It also might related to the manufacturer's location, but that is usually lowercase letters ([see here](https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/monitors/faulty-u2412m-replaced-by-a-u2412mb-what-does-b-stand-for/647f2598f4ccf8a8de9d3273)). Are you sure it is the correct name? It doesn't show up on the DELL product page. There is only a reference on the net to a U2713HMB, which seems to be a name given by a refurbishment company, same thing for P2424HEB I only found it on reseller pages.

Comment: Dell's own website [does not have the "B" at the end](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-24-usb-c-hub-monitor-p2422he/apd/210-bbch/monitors-monitor-accessories). With other Dell monitors in the past, a "B" on the label of the device that did not appear on the website indicated the bezel color "black". This model appears to only come in black, though other models in the past have come with a "W" (white) or "S" (silver).

Comment: @MosheKatz In regards to the model, isn't that what I wrote in the last paragraph? As for the colors, that's a possibility, I'll add it to my answer, do you know util when they use it to describe the color?

Comment: Yes, I saw that you wrote that in the last paragraph, I just included a link to the product page itself as an introductory sentence. Regarding when they use it, first time I remember seeing this was around 15 or 20 years ago when I was cataloging equipment for a local school. I have no idea how they decide when to do it or when not to do it.